# Possible causes of pthread_cond_wait()'s not releasing a mutex?

Tags: c++, pthreads, deadlock

My program is seemingly having a deadlock problem.

Basically I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo();

  void bar();

private:
  void monitor();

  bool condition_;
  pthread_t monitor_;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex_;
  pthread_cond_t cv_;
};
```

In `Foo`'s constructor, I invoke `monitor()` in a separate thread (namely `monitor_`). This `monitor()` function does the following:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
while (true) {
  while (!condition_) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&cv_, &mutex_);
  }
  // do something
  // and then setting condition_ to false
  condition_ = false;
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
```

The `bar()` function is the only public interface (excluding ctor and dtor) of `Foo`. It also needs to acquire the mutex in its execution. My symptom is that `bar()` can never acquire `mutex_`. It looks like `pthread_cond_wait()` does not release the mutex as it is supposed to do. And if I disable the monitor thread (thus no racing condition), then `bar()` can run to its completion without any problem.

Of course, the above code is a stripped-down version of my real code. Actually I think there is no logic error in this code and I'm using pthread correctly. I'm suspecting if there are any other causes for this deadlock situation. Can anyone give a clue on this? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, `mutex_` and `cv_` have been initialized properly with attributes both being NULL in the constructor.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your use of pthreads.  Could you show us the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at your constructor and the bar() function, and possibly if you've accidentally made a copy of the object in question.  I've copied the classes you provided, and my assumptions on how the rest of it operates below.  The program below wakes up every second, and signals the thread.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {
    condition_ = false;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cv_, NULL);
    pthread_create(&monitor_, NULL,
           startFunc, this);
  }

  void bar() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    std::cout << "BAR" << std::endl;
    condition_ = true;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv_);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
  }

private:
  Foo(const Foo&) {};
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) { return *this; };

  static void* startFunc(void* r) {
    Foo* f = static_cast<Foo*>(r);
    f->monitor();
    return NULL;
  }

  void monitor() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    while (true) {
      while (!condition_) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&cv_, &mutex_);
      }
      // do something
      // and then setting condition_ to false
      std::cout << "FOO" << std::endl;
      condition_ = false;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);

  }

  bool condition_;
  pthread_t monitor_;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex_;
  pthread_cond_t cv_;
};


int main() {
  struct timespec tm = {1,0};
  Foo f;

  while(true) {
    f.bar();
    nanosleep(&tm, NULL);
  }

}
```

Comment: This is so weird. I just rebooted, did a "make clean", and then re-make. Surprisingly, it worked. I still cannot figure out why. Maybe it's the OS running out of resources. Anyway, what you said about "accidentally copying an object" warns me a lot. I'll pick this as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that it fails in here:

```
while (!condition_) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&cv_, &mutex_);
}
```

Let's assume, *condition* is false. You enter the while loop and in the first run everything goes fine, i.e. you unlock the mutex and wait on the decision variable. Can it happen that the condition variable changes but not the boolean *condition* ? In that case you would enter pthread_cond_wait with an uninitialized mutex and undefined behaviour can occur...
I guess it would help if you would show the bar() method as well.

Another guess would be thread priorities. Maybe insert a yield to give the threads a better chance to switch.

Comment: No, that is not it.  If the cv were signaled, then the mutex would be re-acquired prior to return of the pthread_cond_wait.  It would then loop (since condition is still false) and then release the lock and wait again.  In fact, I've seen many an erroneous implementation that uses an if, and cannot handle spurious wake ups, which are allowed to happen.

Comment: Thanks, @KPK. I think you were referring to spurious wakeups as @dave-s also suggested. As I'm using a while-loop here, so that is unlikely the cause. Showing `bar()` won't help though, because my trace showed that code in `bar()` starting from `pthread_mutex_lock()` never got a chance to be executed. You were also suggesting me yield thread. Yield who then?

Answer (score 0):

In case you run into this again, I ran into a very similar situation where I was running into a deadlock, where I was expecting cond_wait to release the mutex so that other threads could lock the mutex.

My issue was that I had set the mutex as recursive (with settype->PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP) and was mistakenly locking the mutex twice before the cond_wait call. Since the cond_wait only unlocked it once, the mutex was still locked.  The obvious fix was to only lock it once.  Also, as a lesson learned, I won't be using the recursive mutex setting unless I really need to.